# Filtering doesn't work on a field constructed via a function

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I have this column definition:

```js
{ title:"User name", field:"whatever", formatter:fleetTableUserFormatter, width: '20%', headerFilter:true },
```

And then the `fleetTableUserFormatter`:

```js
function fleetTableUserFormatter(cell){
    let data = cell.getData();
    if (data.user_first_name || data.user_last_name){
        return `${ data.user_first_name } ${ data.user_last_name } [${ data.user_number }]`;
    }
    return 'Undefined';
}
```

And the filtering just doesn't work, it does show up, but when entering valid data, it filters out everything.

I assume I should maybe create a function, and then `headerFilter:myFunction` but I can't google any information about what this function is supposed to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant filter on data created in a formatter.

Formatters are visual only, the don't affect sorting or filtering.

If you want to use sorting or filtering of a column of this sort then you need to use a [Mutator](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/mutators#mutators) to create the data.

This will then be available for use in filtering and sorting

Answer (score 0):

OK, got it, it's in official docs :)

http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/filter#header and then the "Filter Comparison Types" section. Just in case someone googled this question.